# TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I am trying to write a list of a list to a new file, but I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       dowork()   File "C:\Python27\work\accounting\formatting quickbooks file\sdf.py", line 11, in dowork
>       WriteFile()   File "C:\Python27\work\accounting\formatting quickbooks file\sdf.py", line 71, in WriteFile
>       f.write(thefile) TypeError: expected a character buffer object

**How do I write a list of a list to a file?**

This is how i am writing:

```
def WriteFile():
    global thefile
    f = open("output"+'.csv','w')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(thefile)
    f.close()
```

and here is the complete source if you need it:

```
import csv

thefile = []
output = []

def dowork():
    sourceFile='e.csv'
    thefile=ReadFile(sourceFile)
    CleanFile(sourceFile)
    ProcessFile()
    WriteFile()

def ReadFile(filename):
    return list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[1:]

def CleanFile(sourceFile):
    global thefile
    thefiletmp=[]
    for i, line in enumerate(thefile):
        if line[2]=='':
            del thefile[i]
        else:
            thefiletmp.append(line[4:])
    thefile=thefiletmp


def ProcessFile():
    global thefile
    iCompany=1
    iNum=0
    iDate=2
    iAging=3
    iBalance=4
    COMPANIES=GetDistinctValues(1)
    mytemparray=[]
    mytempfile=[]
    for company in COMPANIES:
        for line in thefile:
            if line[iCompany]==company:
                mytemparray.append(line[iCompany])
                mytemparray.append(line[iNum])
                mytemparray.append(line[iDate])
                if line[2] in range(0,31):
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if line[2] in range(31,61):
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if line[2] in range(61,91):
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                if line[2] >90:
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append('0')
                    mytemparray.append(line[iBalance])
                mytempfile.append(mytemparray)
                mytemparray=[]
    thefile=mytempfile

def WriteFile():
    global thefile
    f = open("output"+'.csv','w')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(thefile)
    f.close()

def GetDistinctValues(theColumn):
    return sorted(list(set(line[theColumn] for line in thefile)))
```

Comment: You really should replace the global variable with a variable you pass to each function, and close the files when you're done with them. And now that we can see the whole code, I'd strongly suggest reorganizing it so you have a `ProcessLine` function (you can just reverse the `line` and `company` loops), and just filter line by line, so you don't need a list, and don't need to remove things from the list in-place, and so on. The whole thing would be much simpler that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: expected a character buffer object - while trying to save integer to textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the error message is saying is that you can't write a list to a file, only "a character buffer object", meaning a string or something else that acts a lot like a string.

If you just want to write the list to the file in the same way you'd print them to the console, you can write `str(thefile)` or `repr(thefile)` (or even use the redirect syntax in `print` instead of using `file.write`).

But you're using the `csv` module to read the input, and presumably want the output in the same format, so you probably want to use `csv` to write it too.

You're reading like this:

```
list(csv.reader(open(filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[1:]
```

So write like this:

```
csv.writer(open('foo.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"').writerows(thefile)
```

I should mention that I wouldn't structure the code like this in the first place; I'd do something like this:

```
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
  incsv = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  outcsv = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  incsv.read() # skip first line
  for line in incsv:
    if line[3] != '':
      outcsv.write(ProcessLine(line))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't write a list to a file; you can only write a string. Convert the list to a string in some way, or else iterate over the list and write an element at a time. Or you're using the `csv` module, use that to write to the file.

Calling something other than a file (such as a list) `thefile` is bound to lead to confusion, just by the way.

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Answer (score 2):

thefile is a list of lists, not a character buffer.

```
for sublist in thefile:
    f.write("".join(sublist))  # perhaps
```

there is some bad here, using global, naming a list thefile, ...

(The correct answer is abarnert's).