# '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, csv

I am not sure what the problem is here. I have a csv file I want to filter. I want to remove all lines starting with '@' and all lines where the third column is the string 'chrM'. Im basically setting my code up to be like the answer here:

[TypeError: expected a character buffer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592544/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object)

But Im getting an error.

```
import re
import csv

inputSamFile = 'excerpt'
outSamFile = 'filternoM'

with open(inputSamFile) as inputSam, open(outSamFile, 'wt') as outSam:
    inputSamCont = csv.reader(inputSam, delimiter = '\t')
    outSamCont = csv.writer(outSam, delimiter = '\t')
    for line in inputSamCont:
        if line[0].startswith('@'):
            continue
        elif line[2] == 'chrM':
            continue
        else:
            outSamCont.write(line)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filterMito.py", line 19, in 
    outSamCont.write(ProcessLine(line))
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

What am I doing wrong

Comment: It's `writerow` not `write`...

Comment: I have the same issue but with `writeheader` I'm copying the name from the documentation, how is it that it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for `.writerow()`.

I also ran into this problem, as the documentation I was following used `.write()`, but `csv.writer` objects use `.writerow()`.

Comment: I have the same issue but with `writeheader` I'm copying the name from the documentation, how is it that it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you everything you need to know.

```
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'
```

In your code, you create the object:

```
outSamCont = csv.writer(outSam, delimiter = '\t')
```

then try to call the `.write()` method:

```
outSamCont.write(line)
```

(or, as it is in the traceback

```
outSamCont.write(ProcessLine(line))
```

I'm not sure why you have posted different code to what you're running).

However, that object, a `csv.writer`, does not have the method `write`, hence the error message. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects) for `csv.writer` objects for the list of methods they do have, and choose the appropriate one.