# Python - write data frame into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am looking to write my data frame into csv file using python. I am making use of pandas to build the data frame from my input text file.This is my Code,

```
import pandas
import csv

txt_file = r"sida.txt"
txt = open(txt_file, "r")
txt_string = txt.read()
txt_lines = txt_string.split("\n")
txt_dict = {}
c = csv.writer(open("MYFILE.csv", "wb"))

for txt_line in txt_lines:
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k in txt_dict:
        list = txt_dict.get(k)
    else:
        list = []
    list.append(v)
    txt_dict[k]=list
df=(pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(txt_dict, orient="index"))
print(df)
c.writerow(bytes(df, 'UTF-8'))
```

and when I run this it gives me an error over here in the final line - 
    **c.writerow(bytes(df, 'UTF-8'))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface**. Kindly help me with this. I want my output of the dataframe to be inside my csv file. Thanks in advance.

This is updated code,

```
for txt_line in txt_lines:
    k,v = txt_line.split(":")
    k = k.strip()
    v = v.strip()
    if k in txt_dict:
        list = txt_dict.get(k)
    else:
        list = []
    list.append(v)
    txt_dict[k]=list
df=(pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(txt_dict, orient="index"))
print(df)
c.write(bytes(df, 'UTF-8'))
```

and the error that I am getting is this,  **c.write(bytes(df, 'UTF-8'))
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface

Comment: yes. I went through it. But I am getting this error, when I tried that **c.write(bytes(df, 'UTF-8'))
AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'**

Comment: Add what you tried and the error you get to your question so people can help you better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639531/csv-writer-object-has-no-attribute-write

Comment: Ya I have updated the code and error along with the question.

Comment: Googling the error you get will usually help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You want to use to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv(path + filename)
```