# Python remove ' from string when using CSV writer

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I managed with converting the txt file to .csv with python.

However, now I don't know how to remove the quotes enclosing all strings in my CSV file.

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
 import csv

 with open('UPRN.txt', 'r') as in_file:
 stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
 lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
 with open('UPRN.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(('Name', 'UPRN','ADMIN_AREA','TOWN','STREET','NAME_NUMBER'))
    writer.writerows(lines)
    for lines in writer:
        lines = [x.replace("'","") if x == '*' else x for x in row]
        writer.writerow(lines)
```

but I am getting an error:

**TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not iterable**

The easiest way could be:

[Remove quotes from String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950791/remove-quotes-from-string-in-python)

but the CSV writer has no attributes like write, replace, etc.
['_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639531/csv-writer-object-has-no-attribute-write)

Moreover, I am not sure if a wildcard is needed here:

[Python wildcard search in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427138/python-wildcard-search-in-string)

Is there any quick way of removing the quotes when the CSV module is imported?

Comment: What's with the `if x == '*'`? Of course the string doesn't contain `'` if it's literally `*`

Comment: you are iterating over your csv writer, instead of the lines. should be something like `for line in lines:` then `line = [element.replace("'", "") for element in line]` and `writer.writerow(line)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python csv writer without quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882024/using-python-csv-writer-without-quotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should rather iterate on your `lines` list,

```
with open('UPRN.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = [line.strip().replace("'","") for line in in_file]

with open('UPRN.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(('Name', 'UPRN','ADMIN_AREA','TOWN','STREET','NAME_NUMBER'))

    for line in lines:
        writer.writerow(line.split(","))
```

Comment: The `if` is still pointless, `"*".replace("'", "")` simply returns `"*"`

Comment: NameError: name 'lines' is not defined unfortunately this error I am getting

Comment: @tripleee I have let it although yes it doesn't have much use here

Comment: @MKR I added code for to read the lines. I removed the split(",") as you don't need to split your string I believe

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now I have the string split between every column.

Comment: Should work now