# TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python, pyscripter

I have been trying to print the output to a new text file. But I get the error

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

What I'm trying to do is convert pdf to text and copy the text obtained to a new file.

```
import pyPdf

def getPDFContent():
  content = ""
  # Load PDF into pyPDF
  pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("D:\output.pdf", "rb"))
  # Iterate pages
  for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    # Extract text from page and add to content
    #content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    print pdf.getPage(i).extractText().encode("ascii", "ignore")

  # Collapse whitespace
  #content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
  #return content

  #getPDFContent().encode("ascii", "ignore")
  getPDFContent()

  s =getPDFContent()
  with open('D:\pdftxt.txt', 'w') as pdftxt:
      pdftxt.write(s)
```

I did try to initialize `s` as `str` but then I get the error as "can't assign to function call".

Comment: Your `getPDFContent()` function **doesn't return anything**. `print` is **not** the same thing as `return`.

Comment: @Martijn plus I don't think there's meant to be a couple of recursive calls in there... So I'm guessing the indentation is not exactly reliable either

Comment: Your code sample is a bit of a mess. Can you clean it up (fix the indentation, remove obsolete comments, etc.). Include the *actual attempt*; I suspect the `print` version posted here is not your only version you tried.

Comment: I had even tried return before but the only thing i got was page 1,the rest of pages never appeared in my textfile. But print was the only 1 that worked where in the interpreter displayed the complete output but didn't copy it to a new text file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: expected a character buffer object - while trying to save integer to textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning  anything `getPDFContent()` so basically you are writing `None`.

```
 result=[]
 for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
     result.append(pdf.getPage(i).extractText().encode("ascii", "ignore")) # store all in a list
 return result


 s = getPDFContent()
 with open('D:\pdftxt.txt', 'w') as pdftxt:
    pdftxt.writelines(s) # use writelines to write list content
```

How your code should look:

```
def getPDFContent():
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file("D:\output.pdf", "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    result = []
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        result.append(pdf.getPage(i).extractText().encode("ascii", "ignore"))
    return result

s = getPDFContent()
with open('D:\pdftxt.txt', 'w') as pdftxt:
    pdftxt.writelines(s)
```

Comment: The comments in the function suggest more was tried. But as it stands currently it is a mess.