# TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python

I am running into the following error while writing the value into a file. Can you please help me figure out what is the issue here and how to fix it?

```
row = 649
with open(r'\\loc\dev\Build_ver\build_ver.txt','r+') as f:
    f.write(row)
print row
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latest_rev.py", line 6, in <module>
    f.write(row)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: expected a character buffer object - while trying to save integer to textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming you just want to write the string `'649'` to the file, change `row` to `'649'` or issue `f.write(str(row))`.

Comment: i.e. `write()` won't take an int, so cast `row` to a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what timgeb did or you can do

```
row = str(649)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, in my code:

```
s.translate(table)
```

The `s` obj was `string`. The issue was `s.translate` was expecting a unicode string. So, the fix was to use:

```
unicode(s).translate(table)
```