# how to make a unique data from strings

Tags: python

I have a data like this . the strings are separated by comma.

```
"India1,India2,myIndia     "
"Where,Here,Here   "
"Here,Where,India,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

What I am trying to do is to put them all in one column (one under each other) So it will become like this

```
India1
India2
myIndia
Where
Here
Here
Here
Where
India
uyete
AFD
TTT
```

Then I keep the unique ones which lead to this

```
India1
India2
myIndia
Where
Here
India
uyete
AFD
TTT
```

So I have the first data in a .txtformat and I have tried to use numpyfor this

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

# give a name to my data 
file_name = 'path to my data/test.txt'
# set my output 
with open ( 'output.txt' , 'w' ) as out:
    # read all the lines
    for n , line in enumerate ( open ( file_name ).readlines ( ) ):
        # split each stirg from another one by a comma
        item1 = file_name.split ( ',' )
    myList = ','.join ( map ( str , item1 ) )
    item2 = np.unique ( myList , return_inverse=True )
    # save the data into out
    out.write ( item2 )
```

I was getting `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

I have searched it and I found several post like 
[TypeError: expected a character buffer object - while trying to save integer to textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to)

and If I added `out.seek ( 0 )` I still got the same error

but by changing it to  `out.write ( str(item2 ))`  thanks to [TypeError: expected a character buffer object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439988/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object) I get no error however, the output is showing this

> (array(['/path to the file/test.txt'], 
>         dtype='|S29'), array([0]))

Below is given a soltuion which I tried to use

```
import csv

data = []
def remove_quotes(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.strip ( '"\n' )
with open ( 'test.txt' ) as f:
    reader = csv.reader ( remove_quotes ( f ) )
    for row in reader:
        data.extend ( row )
```

No error but also `data` is not generated

Comment: You can simply read from file, split and put all in a set.

Comment: `file_name.split ( ',' )`. What did you expect that to do?

Comment: See **`unique_everseen`** in the [recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) section of the  [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) documentation.

Comment: @cricket_007 I expected to split strings by `comma`

Comment: @nik why are you splitting a filename?

Comment: File name cannot contain commas. You used the wrong variable

Comment: @Peter Wood  nice point, I was not aware of this `unique_everseen`

Comment: Also `myList` is a string, not a list. You joined `item1` back on the commas that you split by, therefore essentially recreating the comma separated `line`

Comment: @cricket_007 so you mean I should not have used `item1 = file_name.split ( ',' )`

Comment: Why do you want `'path to my data/test.txt'.split(',')`??

Comment: @cricket_007 I thought I should split the data because I want to have each string speerated from the other one   `'path to my data/test.txt'.split(',')`  also if i use `myList = " ".join ( map ( str , item1 ) ) the same empty output`

Comment: No, you want to split the *lines from the file*, not the *file name*. You used the wrong variable, as I've said a few times now. Also, the lines under `item1` should probably be indented

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't get any indent problem. I moved them forward but nothing changes, the output is the same

Comment: I know you don't get an error, but think about the indentation you have. `myList` only gets the **last** `item1` because it is **outside** the for loop

Comment: @cricket_007 if i indent it as you say, then I get an error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack.txt` below contains this:

```
"India1,India2,myIndia"
"Where,Here,Here"
"Here,Where,India,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

Here you go:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("stack.txt", "r") as f:
    # read your data in from the gist site and strip off any new-line characters
    data = [eval(line.strip()) for line in f.readlines()]
    # get individual words into a list
    individual_elements = [word for row in data for word in row.split(",")]
    # remove duplicates and preserve order
    uniques = OrderedDict.fromkeys(individual_elements)   
    # convert from OrderedDict object to plain list
    final = [word for word in uniques]

print(final)
```

Which yields this:

```
['India1', 'India2', 'myIndia', 'Where', 'Here', 'India', 'uyete', 'AFD', 'TTT']
```

Edit: To get your desired output, just print the list in the format you want:

```
print("\n".join(final))
```

Which is equivalent, from an output standpoint, to this:

```
for x in final:
    print(x)
```

Which yields this:

```
India1
India2
myIndia
Where
Here
India
uyete
AFD
TTT
```

Comment: I like your answer already ! just one thing, would it be possible to have the output as a column without any `,`and `'` one under the other ? if so, I accept and like your answer

Comment: `final` is a `list` object, hence why it has `'` and `,` characters separating its string elements. Will update.

Answer (score -1):

Why using numpy??? and I'm not sure if you want to use the same file as input and output

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


# give a name to my data 
inputData = """India1,India2,myIndia
Where,Here,Here   
Here,Where,India,uyete
AFD,TTT"""

# if you want to read the data from a file
#inputData = open(fileName, 'r').readlines()

outputData = ""
tempData = list()
for line in inputData.split("\n"):
    lineStripped = line.strip()
    lineSplit = lineStripped.split(',')
    lineElementsStripped = [element.strip() for element in lineSplit]
    tempData.extend( lineElementsStripped )
tempData = set(tempData)
outputData = "\n".join(tempData)
print("\nInputdata: \n%s" % inputData)
print("\nOutputdata: \n%s" % outputData)
```

Comment: Is maintaining order important? You should probably ask for clarification of the question before providing an answer.

Comment: Everything which is not explicitly requested is not important to me.

Comment: Something like `from collections import OrderedDict; tempData = OrderedDict.fromkeys(tempData).keys()` should preserve the order.

Comment: @not_a_robot what is this `tempData`

Comment: @JDB the order is important for me. Look at my question above. I showed how the output looks like

Comment: @not_a_robot I want to accept your answer if you correct it. I did not down vote your answer. The only problem I have is that the data structure you use is not the same as what I asked. Here I shared the data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63b1a70e913c1453b0de9d7027b5973a if you correct your answer I liked and accept your answer

Comment: @JDB I am going to accept your answer. Please read my comment above. By the way, I did not downvote your answer

Comment: @nik I've added an answer above with the `collections.OrderedDict` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you probably have a csv file. You don't need numpy for that, the included batteries are all you need.

```
 import csv

 data = []
 with open('test.txt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
         data.extend(row)
```

You can `.extend` lists rather than `.append` to them. It's basically like saying

```
for thing in row:
    data.append(thing)
```

That will still leave the duplicates, though. If you don't care about order you can just make it a `set` and call `.update()` instead of extend:

```
 data = set()
 with open('test.txt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
         data.extend(row)
```

And now everything is unique. But if you care about order you'll have to filter things down a bit:

```
unique_data = []
for thing in data:
    if thing not in unique_data:
        unique_data.append(thing)
```

If your `test.txt` file contains this text:

```
"India1,India2,myIndia     "
"Where,Here,Here   "
"Here,Where,India,uyete"
"AFD,TTT"
```

And not

```
India1,India2,myIndia     
Where,Here,Here   
Here,Where,India,uyete
AFD,TTT
```

Then you don't quite have a csv. You can either fix what's generating your csv or manually remove the quotes *or* just fix it on the fly.

```
def remove_quotes(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.strip('"\n')

reader = csv.reader(remove_quotes(f))
```

Comment: Does your file literally contain `"foo,bar,thing,quux"\n"next,line,goes,here"\n`? If so you'll want to either fix your csv or wrap the file.

Comment: yes I share an example here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63b1a70e913c1453b0de9d7027b5973a

Comment: BTW, the quotes are included in the file, apparently... There's been multiple questions from OP containing this data

Comment: @nik well then you definitely want the `remove_quotes` wrapper.

Comment: @Wayne Werner where to put the last `remove_quotes?`my mean merging the remove_quotes with the first solution you gave , how to pass the reader to that ?

Comment: @Wayne Werner even if I correct my data, without quotation, your first method does not produce any output

Comment: @cricket_007 I posted how I used your solution above which does not generate anything

Comment: @nik I didn't give you a solution - I pointed out a logical flaw in your code

Comment: @nik I assumed that you would put this in your existing code and do your own output.

Comment: @Wayne Werner even without the quotation your solution does not work

Comment: "does not work" is not [mcve]. If you can't explain what you expect then how do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: @Wayne Werner does not work means I showed you , I shared with you a data and I showed which output I am looking for. Print the output of the first code you gave , you see what I mean with not working?

Comment: @Wayne Werner   **This** is the data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63b1a70e913c1453b0de9d7027b5973a  I want to have Unique Strings . Is it not clear enough???

Comment: No, because my code produces unique strings and you say that it doesn't. So apparently you mean something *entirely different than what you're saying*.

Comment: @Wayne Werner print the input and output in your answer then

Comment: If you can't figure out how to add a print function you may want to go back to the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)