# CSV'ify a variable

Tags: python, csv

I have a python variable that holds a string ready to be converted into a csv file. This is what my variable contains:-

```
myvar="ID,Name\n1001,Tania\n1002,Geraldina"
```

How do I make this variables into a csv file? I dont want the "\n"s and the "'s. Instead I want real line breaks..

EG:This is what I want inside my csv file (myvar.csv)

```
ID,Name
1001,Tania
1002,Geraldina
```

I tried this:

```
with open("myvar.csv","w+") as out:
    json.dump(myvar,out)
```

But it just inserts the string as is.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more code in your question.

Comment: Hi @AnttiHaapala. I  added what I tried in my question. Can you please remove the downvote? :) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable is already in csv format. Just write the variable contents into the csv file.

```
myvar="ID,Name\n1001,Tania\n1002,Geraldina"
with open("myvar.csv", "w") as w:
    w.write(str(myvar))
```

`\n` in the `myvar` is a real new line character not a literal `\n`

Comment: TypoError :expected a character buffer object at w.write(myvar)

Comment: try `r+` instead of `w`

Comment: that didn't change anything, unfortunately :(

Comment: oh, it works for me. Which version are you running? did you use the with open statement?

Comment: 2.7.3.. Yes i did use the open statement

Comment: use `with open`.. and change the type of `var` to string. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72556/discussion-between-tania-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in csv.reader(io.StringIO(myvar)):
    print(row)
```

It's for python3, for python2 it would be `StringIO.StringIO`.

Basically instead of actual file you're using file-like object.

With writing:

```
In [170]: with open('myvar.csv', 'w') as f:
   .....:     writer = csv.writer(f)
   .....:     for row in csv.reader(io.StringIO(myvar)):
   .....:         writer.writerow(row)
```

upd. Okay I'm overthinking it.. all you really need is just write to file, no csv functionality, since you already have "csv" data in your string. Just as @Avinash wrote. So `f.write` is good enough.

Comment: Can you please add lines to your code that involves writing these rows to a new file naming it myvar.csv?

Comment: Hi, can your write support unicode strings (multilingual strings)?

Comment: @Tania Try reading https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, since the accepted answer works with unicode for me after only adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top of the file (2.7.3).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easily:

```
myvar = "ID,Name\n1001,Tania\n1002,Geraldina"

with open('myvar.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(myvar+'\n')
```