# Python Pretty Table output to text file

Tags: python

Is there a way to redirect pretty table output to a text file rather than just the screen?

From https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/wiki/Tutorial

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])
x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names
x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
print x
```

Comment: just write the contents of variable to a file using file writer object..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just write the contents of variable `x` to that file.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])
x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names
x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
with open('file', 'w') as w:
    w.write(str(x))
```

Comment: in the last line:  w.write(x)

Comment: check my update.. you need to convert `x` to the type string before writing. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787008/3297613

Answer (score 0):

The above write method wil not work and will end up raising exception

**instead use get_string() method**

```
    with open('file', 'w') as w:
        w.write(x.get_string())
```

Reference:
https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#miscellaneous-things