# Parsing word documents into excel file with single word per row

Tags: python, database, excel

I am working with a large amount of word files where i would like to make an excel file with where each word file is a column and each word in each document is a row.  I am new to python; how would I do this?

I have this code to separate the words:

```
import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))

with open('data10.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        w = f.read().translate(remove)
        print(word.lower())
```

I just need to know how to get each word to be a row in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this would be to pipe this to a csv file from the command line

```
python myscript.py > words.csv
```

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Parse", line 7, in <module>
    w = f.read().translate(remove)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: try changing 'r' to 'rb'

Comment: dunno man take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to and if that doesnt' help google for "TypeError: expected a character buffer" to see if you can work it out