# applying function to all columns in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am extremely new to numpy.

Just wondering why does this not work.

```
print items['description']
```

Yields

```
0                            Продам Камаз 6520 20 тонн
1                                      Весь в тюнинге.
2    Телефон в хорошем состоянии, трещин и сколов н...
3    Отличный подарок на новый год от "китайской ap...
4        Лыжные ботинки в хорошем состоянии, 34 размер
Name: description, dtype: object
```

Trying to apply this method to all the rows in this col.

```
items['description'] = vectorize_sentence(items['description'].astype(str))
```

This is the function definition for vectorize sentence.

```
def vectorize_sentence(self, sentence):
    # Tokenize 
    print 'sentence', sentence

    tkns = self._tokenize(sentence)
    vec = None
    for tkn in tkns: 
        print 'tkn', tkn.decode('utf-8')
        print type(tkn)
        if self.model[tkn.decode('utf-8')]:
            vec = sum(vec, self.model[tkn.decode('utf-8')])
    #vec = sum([self.model[x] for x in tkns if x in self.model])
    #print vec
def _tokenize(self, sentence):
    return sentence.split(' ')
```

***Error Message:***

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your getting that error because `'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`. Mainly, the `.astype(str)` does not return a single long string like you think it does

```
items = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['bob loblaw', 'john wayne', 'lady gaga loves to sing']})
sentence = items['description'].astype(str)
sentence.split(' ')
```

now try

```
sentence = ' '.join(x for x in items['description'])
sentence.split(' ')
```

and then implementing in your function

```
def _tokenize(self, sentence):
    return ' '.join(x for x in items['description']).split(' ')
```

Comment: How do i achieve what i want to achieve then. Thanks

Comment: Not really. Got an error: "expected a character buffer object"

Comment: Well that is probably when you are writing to a file see [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786941/typeerror-expected-a-character-buffer-object-while-trying-to-save-integer-to). In any case, it certainly is not related to this question, so please mark this one as closed and post a new question with more details if need be